# Is Eclipse Galileo compatible to Google Plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt

They don't seem to mention which Eclipse Version must be used...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[It's not yet compatible with Galileo](http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/download.html), support is "coming soon".

Answer (score 3):

Google Plugin for Eclipse Galileo has just been released today.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install Ganymede to get it working